# How to choose random line from a 2 lists and combine them

Tags: html, linux, bash, random, generator

Is there a website that can do this or any command?
i been searching and cant find anything on this random generator from 2 lists

here for example

```
file 1
one one
five eight
one two three

file 2 
canada
usa
netherland
```

OUTPUT: one one canada or five eight netherland

any help is appriciated

Comment: What have you done so far?  Please see how to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Read the files into two arrays.
- Generate two random integers as index for the arrays (make sure the range is right)
- Read the values and concatenate them